# Can't use a class defined in an npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package

I am trying to use a typescript-parser:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-parser

but I'm having difficulties with using the package properly.

I installed the package successfully using `npm install`; when I run `npm list --depth=0` it shows up in the list.

Eventually, I tried running the following line of code that is suggested in the link attached above (using `node` command):

```
const parser = new TypescriptParser();
```

but the problem is that I get the following error:

```
const parser = new TypescriptParser();
           ^

ReferenceError: TypescriptParser is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\parser_example.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js             (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Alternatively, I tried running this:

```
const TypescriptParser = require('typescript-parser');

const parser = new TypescriptParser();
```

yet I still get a (different) error:

```
const parser = new TypescriptParser();
           ^

TypeError: TypescriptParser is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\parser_example.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

It seems as if although the package was installed, it doesn't recognize the class TypescriptParser.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How did you import `TypescriptParser`?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. Instead of `require('typescript-parser')` I tried using `require('TypescriptParser')` but I got the error `Error: Cannot find module 'TypescriptParser'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing using:

```
import { TypescriptParser } from 'typescript-parser';
```

Comment: Using that, I get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and it works for me :

index.js file

```
const parser = require('typescript-parser');

const parser = new TypescriptParser();
```

I run it with `node index.js`

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

index.js file

```js
const tp = require('typescript-parser');
const parser = new tp.TypescriptParser();
```